# Add Letter to Appendix Numbering in Quarto

Tags: r, pdf, latex, quarto

Is there a way to restart section numbering, figure numbering, and table numbering in the appendix of a Quarto document? I need to knit to PDF. In the reprex below, I would like the section headers to look like...

- Section 1
- Section 2
- A. First Appendix
- A.1 More Results
- A.2 Even More Results

```
---
title: "Test"
format: 
  pdf:
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 4
editor: visual
---

# Section 1

Text

# Section 2

Text

# First Appendix {.appendix}

## More Results

Text

## Even More Results

Text
```

Here is what the output looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart the section counter before appendix section and change the number format also. Do the same for figure and table too!

````
---
title: "Test"
format: 
  pdf:
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 4
editor: visual
---

# Section 1

Text

# Section 2

Text

See @fig-plot

See @fig-another-plot

see @tbl-my-tab

\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}

# First Appendix {.appendix}

## More Results

Text

## Even More Results

Text

## Plot

\newpage

```{r}
#| label: fig-plot
#| fig-cap: A plot

plot(1:10)
```

\newpage

```{r}
#| label: fig-another-plot
#| fig-cap: Another plot

plot(rnorm(100))

```

## Table

\newpage

```{r}
#| label: tbl-my-tab
#| tbl-cap: A table

knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
```
````

Also as an alternative, you can use the latex package `chngcntr` to do change counter for figure and tables within appendix.

````
---
title: "Test"
format: 
  pdf:
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 4
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \usepackage{chngcntr}
editor: visual

---

# Section 1

Text

# Section 2

Text

See @fig-plot

See @fig-another-plot

see @tbl-my-tab

\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}


# First Appendix {.appendix}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\counterwithin{table}{section}


## More Results

Text

## Even More Results

Text

\newpage


## Plot

```{r}
#| label: fig-plot
#| fig-cap: A plot

plot(1:10)
```

\newpage

```{r}
#| label: fig-another-plot
#| fig-cap: Another plot

plot(rnorm(100))

```

\newpage

## Table

```{r}
#| label: tbl-my-tab
#| tbl-cap: A table

knitr::kable(head(mtcars))
```
````

And if you want the numbering for tables and figures nested within appendix subsection, use instead,

```latex
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin{table}{subsection}
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you do something similar for tables and figures?

Comment: Thanks! And sorry for not marking this as the answer before. Hit "upvote" instead!

Comment: Shafee -- how would you add a section label ```{#first-appendix}``` to this header?

Comment: @RyanBaxter-King, Add a section label where? Sorry I am confused and I would recommend create a separate question :).

Comment: No worries! Will add another question if necessary.

Comment: The link in the TOC is no longer consistent with this solution unfortunately; it links to a different section.

Comment: How can we achieve this with html?